Does the series over the bump function's derivatives at 0 converge?
Define $f$ as the well known bump function:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) & |x| \lt 1 \\0 & |x|\ge 1\end{cases}
$$
Does the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(0)
$$
converge?
Answers such as this show that the derivatives of any test function cannot be bounded, however they don't give any lower bounds that would prove a series such as the present one divergent. Numerically calculating the first few partial sums shows that the series seems to be growing rapidly but I have no idea how to find a proof.

Note that for any analytic function $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ on a neighborhood of zero, one cannot have $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(0)$ converge or even $f^{(k)}(0)$ bounded unless the function is entire since $k!a_k=f^{(k)}(0)$ so if $|f^{(k)}(0)| \le M$ one has $|a_k| \le M/k!$ so the power series has infinite radius of convergence.
Trivially here $f$ (which is analytic near $0$ as a composition of analytic functions) has singularities at $\pm 1$ so just by general theory $|f^{(k)}(0)|$ is highly unbounded (for even $k$ as the odd derivatives at zero are $0$ since $f$ even function).
A more interesting question is if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(0)/k!$ converges (it is Abel summable to zero but convergence is trickier)

How would I show that f(x) is analytic on some neighbourhood of zero? The only way I know would be showing that the Taylor series error vanishes, but we don't now much about the derivatives here.

it is a composition of analytic functions $\exp, \frac{1}{x^2-1}$ so it is obviously analytic
